# Can outlook (web) notify me that I have email?

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-app

I have two email accounts.  One of them I use every day.  The other one, I have to fire up a VPN, authenticate through a firewall, and then run Outlook Web Access.  Triple-yuck.

I'd like to set up a rule that says "Whenever I receive an email to annoyingaccount@company.com, send an email to mydailyaccount@myworkplace.com letting me know to check annoyingaccount."  I <strike>do not want</strike> am not allowed to forward the actual email to mydailyaccount.  I simply want a notice that email is waiting for me.

I see options that will let me forward the email or send a text message, but I don't see an option to just send a boilerplate email.  Is there something I'm missing, or a "trick" I need to do, or am I just out of luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not an option like this in the Rules Wizard.
You can forward the email to your account and use rules to:

1. File the AnnoyingAccount email in a folder (so it is out of the way)
2. Display an a custom message in your MyDailyAccount email.

Take a look at the the **display a specific message in the New Item Alert window** option found on the 2nd screen of the Rules Wizard.

Here is a quick How To:
http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/newmailalert.htm